# Obtain earliest date from a table according to summary value

Tags: powerbi-desktop, dashboard, gantt-chart

I have a table as follows, which has a category and some dates

[image]

I want to get (i) the earliest date for each category and (ii) the latest date from the category. Basically Im trying to get a Gantt chart visual between the two dates, based on the name

For example, alpha would run from 3May22 to 3 Aug22 on the chart since that effectively the start and end date of the category

I tried to drag my columns into the Gantt chart but I end up with a bunch of rows for each task (e.g. alpha, alpha, alpha) while I want to have the start date from the earliest alpha and the end date from the oldest alpha in one line.

Not sure if I need a measure (I think so) or a new column but I'm a bit stuck

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found it, hopefully of use to someone else in the same boat.

PowerBI allows you to group the categories together under the visuals edit tab

[image]

I clicked that and suddenly everything looked good!